# Inserting values in desired interval in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This should be an relatively easy task.
I tried with both match function and find function, however I can't get it to work.

This is an example:
[image]

This is what I'm trying to obatin:
[image]

I overwrite whatever is in A1 and B1 by some desired strings.
I replace 'SubTotal' by 'Total'.

Column C to F contains some random noise, and I would like to replace it by a "counter". It works as desired, but I would like to automate it by replacing "6" in the for loop with the number of the column containing "Total"-1.

Any ideas how to get it to work?

Here is my code:

```
Sub test()
    Set sht = Worksheets(1)
    sht.Cells(1, "A").Value = "Name"
    sht.Cells(1, "B").Value = "Age"
    sht.Cells.Replace What:="*Total*", Replacement:="Total"
    For i = 3 To 6
        sht.Cells(1, i).Value = i - 2
    Next
End Sub
```

**Solution**

Apparently I used the find function wrong.
Here is a working solution with the find function.

```
Sub test()
    Dim search As Range
    Dim n As Integer
    Set sht = Worksheets(1)
    sht.Cells(1, "A").Value = "Name"
    sht.Cells(1, "B").Value = "Age"
    sht.Cells.Replace What:="*Total*", Replacement:="Total"
    Set search = sht.Rows(1).Find(What:="Total", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    n = search.Column - 1
    For i = 3 To n
        sht.Cells(1, i).Value = i - 2
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Use COUNTIF formula.

Comment: Try declaring a range `Dim rngT as Range`, then using `Find` to determine the above range (Total) and then use `rngT.Offset(0, -1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Replace and Count

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Const cRow As Long = 1
    Const First As Long = 3
    
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim colNum As Long
    Dim Last As Variant
    
    Set sht = Worksheets(1)
    sht.Cells(cRow, "A").Value = "Name"
    sht.Cells(cRow, "B").Value = "Age"
    sht.Rows(cRow).Replace What:="*Total*", Replacement:="Total"
    Last = Application.Match("Total", Rows(cRow), 0)
    
    If Not IsError(Last) Then
        For colNum = First To Last - 1
            sht.Cells(cRow, colNum).Value = colNum - First + 1
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Or:

```
Sub test2()
    Const cRow As Long = 1
    Const First As Long = 3
    
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim colNum As Long
    Dim Last As Variant
    
    Set sht = Worksheets(1)
    sht.Cells(cRow, First - 2).Value = "Name"
    sht.Cells(cRow, First - 1).Value = "Age"
    sht.Rows(cRow).Replace What:="*Total*", Replacement:="Total"
    Last = Application.Match("Total", Rows(cRow), 0)
    
    If Not IsError(Last) Then
        For colNum = First To Last - 1
            sht.Cells(cRow, colNum).Value = colNum - First + 1
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use code like this:-

```
Sub test()

    Dim Arr As Variant
    
    Arr = Array("Name", "Age", 1, 2, 3, 4, "Total")
    Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(Arr) + 1).Value = Arr
End Sub
```

Note that the numbers 1 thru 4 will be inserted as numbers. If you want them to be text surround tghem with quotation marks like this, `Arr = Array("Name", "Age", "1", "2", "3", "4", "Total")`